# TensorFlow vs PyTorch convolution confusion

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I am confused on how to replicate Keras (TensorFlow) convolutions in PyTorch.

In Keras, I can do something like this. (the input size is `(256, 237, 1, 21)` and the output size is `(256, 237, 1, 1024)`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.random.normal((256,237,1,21))
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=1024, kernel_size=5,padding="same")(x)
print(y.shape) 
(256, 237, 1, 1024)
```

However, in PyTorch, when I try to do the same thing I get a different output size:

```
import torch.nn as nn
x = torch.randn(256,237,1,21)
m = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=237, out_channels=1024, kernel_size=(1,5))
y = m(x)
print(y.shape)
torch.Size([256, 1024, 1, 17])
```

I want PyTorch to give me the same output size that Keras does:

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381052/converting-keras-tensorflow-convolutional-neural-networks-to-pytorch-convoluti) seems to imply that Keras filters are PyTorch's `out_channels` but thats what I have. I tried to add the padding in PyTorch of `padding=(0,503)` but that gives me `torch.Size([256, 1024, 1, 1023])` but that still not correct. This also takes so much longer than keras does so I feel that I have incorrectly assigned a parameter.

How can I replicate what Keras did with convolution in PyTorch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In TensorFlow, [`tf.keras.layers.Conv1D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D) takes in a tensor of shape `(batch_shape + (steps, input_dim))`. Which means that what is commonly known as channels appears on the last axis. For instance in 2D convolution you would have `(batch, height, width, channels)`. **This is different from PyTorch** where the channel dimension is right after the batch axis: [`torch.nn.Conv1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html) takes in shapes of `(batch, channel, length)`. So you will need to permute two axes.

For `torch.nn.Conv1d`:

- `in_channels` is the number of channels in the input tensor
- `out_channels` is the number of filters, *i.e.* the number of channels the output will have
- `stride` the step size of the convolution
- `padding` the zero-padding added to both sides

In PyTorch there is no option for `padding='same'`, you will need to choose `padding` correctly. Here `stride=1`, so `padding` must equal to `kernel_size//2` (*i.e.* `padding=2`) in order to maintain the length of the tensor.

---

In your example, since `x` has a shape of `(256, 237, 1, 21)`, in TensorFlow's terminology it will be considered as an input with:

- a batch shape of `(256, 237)`,
- `steps=1`, so the length of your 1D input is `1`,
- `21` input channels.

Whereas in PyTorch, `x` of shape `(256, 237, 1, 21)` would be:

- batch shape of `(256, 237)`,
- `1` input channel
- a length of `21`.

---

Have kept the input in both examples below (TensorFlow *vs.* PyTorch) as `x.shape=(256, 237, 21)` assuming `256` is the batch size, `237` is the length of the input sequence, and 21 is the number of channels (*i.e.* the input dimension, what I see as the dimension on each timestep).

In TensorFlow:

```
>>> x = tf.random.normal((256, 237, 21))
>>> m = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=1024, kernel_size=5, padding="same")
>>> y = m(x)
>>> y.shape
TensorShape([256, 237, 1024])
```

In PyTorch:

```
>>> x = torch.randn(256, 237, 21)
>>> m = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=21, out_channels=1024, kernel_size=5, padding=2)
>>> y = m(x.permute(0, 2, 1))
>>> y.permute(0, 2, 1).shape
torch.Size([256, 237, 1024])
```

So in the latter, you would simply work with `x = torch.randn(256, 21, 237)`...

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch now has out of the box same convolution operation you can take a look at this link [Same convolution][1]

```
class InceptionNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, in_1x1, in_3x3reduce, in_3x3, in_5x5reduce, in_5x5, in_1x1pool):
        super(InceptionNet, self).__init__()
        self.incep_1 = ConvBlock(in_channels, in_1x1, kernel_size=1, padding='same')
```

Note a same convolution only supports the default stride value which is 1 anything other won't work.
[1]: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html